# Position is not a valid member of Model "Workspace.Tower"

Tags: lua, roblox

(this is roblox studio by the way) I run the following script:

local tower = script.Parent
local enemy = workspace.Enemy

local distance = tower.Position - enemy.Position

print(distance)

It says: "Position is not a valid member of Model "Workspace.Tower""

Tower is just a union of simple parts

This script is the child of the Tower

Position is a property of Tower

Tower is named Tower

Enemy is named Enemy

it is .Postion, not .position

I'm not sure what to do. Any ideas?

I expected the difference between the Tower Position and the Enemy position to appear in the Output as a print.

What happened was nothing appeared in the Output besides the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t set a models’ position directly. You would either need to use :MoveTo(vector3) or :PivotToCFrame(cframe) on the model to move it.

Answer (score 0):

```
local tower,enemy=script.Parent,workspace.Enemy 
local distance=(tower:GetBoundingBox().p-enemy.Humanoid.Torso.Position).magnitude
print(distance)
```

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation